# Android: Accurate way to retrieve the phone's angle?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sensors

Is there a way to retrieve an Android phone's angle? If I place my phone flat on a table, the angle should be 0 degrees, if I place my phone upright against a wall, the angle should be 90 degrees. I am wondering if I can leverage any sensors built-in to the phone's hardware to accomplish this.

Comment: Please review my answer and mark it appropriately. If you need further help, elaborate on your question so that I and others may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Position sensors are useful for determining a device's physical position in the world's frame of reference. For example, you can use the geomagnetic field sensor in combination with the accelerometer to determine a device's position relative to the magnetic north pole. You can also use these sensors to determine a device's orientation in your application's frame of reference. Position sensors are not typically used to monitor device movement or motion, such as shake, tilt, or thrust (for more information, see Motion sensors).
>
> ....Pitch (degrees of rotation about the x axis). This is the angle between a plane parallel to the device's screen and a plane parallel to the ground. If you hold the device parallel to the ground with the bottom edge closest to you and tilt the top edge of the device toward the ground, the pitch angle becomes positive. Tilting in the opposite direction— moving the top edge of the device away from the ground—causes the pitch angle to become negative. The range of values is -180 degrees to 180 degrees.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position